# Determine current VMWare vmx used

Tags: linux, vmware, vmware-workstation

How do I determine the current VMWare workstation vmx name a user is currently using? Is there a Linux command to determine this that can be run on the Host OS?

This command will be used to verify to a user in a bash script that they are using the correct version of the vmx file (I think that's what it is called)

I know someone can easily look by hovering over the top of the screen to see, but I have people that work in full screen and sometimes never check the version.

Also, Is there way to determine what vmx version was used to save a file originating from a VM?

Comment: If you open the configuration file there should be a line contained within it that indicates which version it's been configured to.  Likewise VMWare Workstation also should indicate it.

Comment: Thanks but what I'm looking for is to do something programmatically or by a Linux command. Everything you mentiomed is manual

Comment: You should be able to do this with VMWare PowerCLI, PowerShell Core should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can inspect the list of processes, then you can look for `vmware-vmx` processes and inspect its command-line arguments, which will list the full path to the `.vmx` configuration file used.

Of course, if a user is running multiple VMs, it won't tell you what VM the user is *currently* using (i.e., which VM has grabbed input).  Knowing that doesn't really make a lot of sense to me, though.

> Also, Is there way to determine what vmx version was used to save a file originating from a VM?

If you're talking about files in the guest, then no, guest applications generally have no knowledge that they're running in a VM.  If you're talking about the VM's configuration files themselves, the best you can do is look at the VM's hardware version in the `.vmx` file, but even that wouldn't tell what VMware product wrote it.